# How to detect when an App crashed on Bluestacks

Tags: macros, bluestacks

I an running a script on Bluestacks for a game. Sometimes, the game gets crashed. I want to make a Program that will detect when the App crashes, and then do certain action.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Once you app goes into crash state either your system will get freeze may because of low configuration as it will consume lots of resources and our script is running into Bluestacks environment. Script have no control over this situation. It takes input only from mouse and keyboard strokes.

Can you please open your **Settings (gear wheel** to the right) and match these settings and see if that resolves the issue for you?

### Engine Tab:

> *Graphics Engine*: Performance
> *Graphics Renderer*: OpenGL
> *GPU Settings*: Prefer dedicated graphics (if possible)
> *ASTC*: Hardware decoding (if possible)
> *CPU*: 4 Cores
> *RAM*: 4 GB
> *ABI*: Auto

### Device Tab:

> *Device Profile:* One Plus 3T